# read-byte ignores eof-error-p inside SBCL gray stream

Tags: stream, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

So, I'm specializing `read-byte` method using gray streams on SBCL. I've run into a peculiar behaviour where `eof-error-p` argument seems to be ignored. It could be I'm missing some trivial mistake in my code, but I've looked through it a dozen times already, and I just don't see it.

Suppose there is a file `test.txt` with a single byte, say

```sh
echo -n 7 > test.txt
```

I expect the following code to return `:eof`

```lisp
(defclass binary-input-stream (fundamental-binary-input-stream)
  ((stream :initarg :stream :reader stream-of)))

(defmethod stream-read-byte ((stream binary-input-stream))
  (format t "~a~%" "It's me, all right")
  (read-byte (stream-of stream) nil :eof))

(defun make-binary-input-stream (stream)
  (make-instance 'binary-input-stream :stream stream))

(with-open-file (in "test.txt" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (setq in (make-binary-input-stream in))
  (read-byte in)
  (read-byte in))
```

However, SBCL throws an `END-OF-FILE` exception. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an addition to coredump's answer.  In particular I think that the behaviour of your code is correct: SBCL is doing the right thing in its implementation of Gray streams, and it should indeed be signalling an exception here.

In your code the pattern of calls is:

- `read-byte` (with no optional arguments) on your `binary-input-stream` calls `stream-read-byte` on the same stream;
- your method on `stream-read-byte` directly calls `read-byte` on the stream you have wrapped, asking for no error and a return on EOF of `:eof`, and returns the value of that call without further inspection;
- that in turn presumably goes through the `stream-read-byte` method of the wrapped stream, but we don't need to worry about that.

So, what should this do?  Well, I am not sure where the right place for the definitive documentation of Gray streams is, but [here is something which may be close to it](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Issues/stream-definition-by-user.html).

In that document, `stream-read-byte` is defined:

```
STREAM-READ-BYTE  stream            [Generic Function]

    Used by READ-BYTE; returns either an integer, or the symbol :EOF if the
    stream is at end-of-file.
```

`read-byte` is then defined as:

```
(defun READ-BYTE (binary-input-stream &optional (eof-errorp t) eof-value)
  (check-for-eof (stream-read-byte binary-input-stream) 
                 binary-input-stream eof-errorp eof-value))
```

Finally `check-for-eof` is defined as:

```
(defun check-for-eof (value stream eof-errorp eof-value)
  (if (eq value :eof)
      (report-eof stream eof-errorp eof-value)
    value))
```

(I think the last two definitions really mean that 'the implementation needs to do something whose behaviour is equivalent to this', and in particular it needs to do that in the case where the stream is a Gray stream.)

So any method on `stream-read-byte` *must not* return `:eof` unless the stream is at end of file, and in particular doing so will cause an exception to be signalled (or will cause `report-eof` to be invoked, anyway, and it may or may not signal an exception).  And `:eof` is the *only* special value that `stream-read-byte` can return.

Well, your method on `stream-read-byte` does indeed return `:eof` to indicate end of file, having carefully suppressed the exception that the inner call yo `read-byte` would otherwise signal, so it's a well-behaved method.

But then the *outer* call to `read-byte`, as defined above, sees this EOF value and dutifully raises an exception for you.  Which is, in fact, what you asked for, because you did not ask to suppress the exception in those calls.

If you don't want an exception you need to make sure that the outer calls to `read-byte` ask for one not to happen, by, for instance:

```
(with-open-file (in "test.txt" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (with-open-stream (bin (make-binary-input-stream in))
    (values (read-byte bin nil ':eof)
            (read-byte bin nil ':eof))))
```

For a one-byte file this should return the byte in the file and `:eof`.

Comment: Thanks. Both yours and @coredump answers were helpful. I accept your answer for the short but useful remark "SBCL is doing the right thing". Now that see how it works, I agree that SBCL's logic is most reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the example, and the debugger shows (under Slime):

```
Backtrace:
  0: (READ-BYTE #<BINARY-INPUT-STREAM {1039A8D933}> T NIL)
  1: ((LAMBDA ()))
  ...
```

By moving the cursor to frame 0 (i.e. `read-byte`) and pressing <kbd>v</kbd>, the editor shows the definition of `read-byte` in `sbcl/src/code/stream.lisp` (I build it from source):

```
(defun read-byte (stream &optional (eof-error-p t) eof-value)
  (declare (explicit-check))
  (if (ansi-stream-p stream)
      (ansi-stream-read-byte stream eof-error-p eof-value nil)
      ;; must be Gray streams FUNDAMENTAL-STREAM
      (let ((byte (stream-read-byte stream)))
        (if (eq byte :eof)
            (eof-or-lose stream eof-error-p eof-value) ;; <<<< CURSOR HERE
            (the integer byte)))))
```

It turns out `:eof` is already used by SBCL to indicate the enf of line, and since the top-level call to `read-byte` does not ignore errors, this cause the condition to be signaled.

Replacing the `:eof` keyword by another one, say `:my-eof`, is not good either since the returned value is not a byte. But if you return `-1`, the test passes (the source stream is a stream of unsigned-bytes, but your wrapper may return -1 without errors).